# Do I need a second TLS certificate for dev.fancydomain.com?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm deploying an app on my kubernetes cluster. I successfully used cert-manager to create a TLS certificate for `fancydomain.com`. When a user accesses `fancydomain.com`, an Ingress rule redirects the request to a backend service in the `default` k8s namespace.

I'm now provisioning a `dev` namespace for...well, development. I would like the path `dev.fancydomain.com` to redirect to the `dev` namespace. My question is: do I need another TLS certificate? If a dev user tries to visit `dev.fancydomain.com`, will they see a warning if the certificate is different from `fancydomain.com` ?